# Entity Framework ObjectQuery.Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an object with two objects as properties (`User`, `PrimaryNode`), both could potentially be null, see below:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public Node PrimaryNode { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework 6 to populate the `Item` object and using chained includes to populate the `PrimaryNode` and `User` objects within it.

When the first chained Include has a null object then the whole object returns as null, for example:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var item = db.Items.Include(i => i.User).Include(n => n.PrimaryNode).FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == id);
}
```

If in the above example `i.User` is null then the `item` variable is null. Whats the best way of populating both the sub-objects in a way that if a sub-object is null then the parent object and the other sub-object will still be populated?

Comment: Make `PrimaryNode` and `User` virtual and map them as optional to `Item`?

Comment: I agree with the statement made by @octavioccl - there is nothing wrong with your query. In my testing, that query will populate the Node object even if there is no User object linked to the Item.

Comment: I can now confirm, there is nothing wrong with the above approach, I had simplified what was rather a complex class. The issue in my case was that as well as having a User object, I also had a UserId property (as I have seen recommended in some circles - so you can get the id without having to load the User object) - it was in fact this property that was causing problems, due to the way it was set-up it resulted in the query being an inner join to the User table. My apologies and thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your issue is due to the `Include` calls. According with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

> This extension method calls the [Include(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the
>   `IQueryable` source object, if such a method exists. *If the source
>   `IQueryable` does not have a matching method, then this method does
>   nothing*.

In other words is going to be translated to:

```
 var item = db.Items.Include("User").Include("PrimaryNode").FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == id);
```

My question is, are you sure you have an `Item` with that id properly related with existing rows in `Users` and `PrimaryNodes` tables in your DB?. When you call `Include` method at the end is going to be translated to a join, so if the FK of your relationship  doesn't match with the PK that reference, your query should not return what you are expecting.

Anyways, if you want to try another variant to load related properties you can use [Explicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit):

```
var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == id);
context.Entry(item).Reference(p => p.PrimaryNode).Load(); 
context.Entry(item).Reference(p => p.User).Load();
```

Comment: Also keep in mind you can use Lambdas. `db.Items.Include(item => Item.User)`. I bring this up because it's a little more refactor friendly.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the Explicit Loading example will result in three calls to the database? Whereas using chained Includes makes a single call to the database with joins.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you use Lazy loading int his situation. Just make the `User` and `PrimaryNode` virtual:

```
public class Item
{
   [Key]
   public int ItemId { get; set; }
   public string ItemName { get; set; }
   public virtual Node PrimaryNode { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var db = new MyContext();
var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This won't work in my scenario as, if I understand Lazy loading correctly, I'm working in a disconnected scenario. I'm getting data from the db and returning it to a web page for display.

Comment: @AndyE...You're Welcome. Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, I think your issue is not due to the Includes. However, I think the following method has value. It is functionally equivalent to what you are already doing with the chained includes, but I think it has several benefits including making the intention of the code clear to the user.

The includes can be placed in Extension methods:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public static class EntityExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<Item> IncludePrimaryNode(this IQueryable<Item> query)
        {
            // eager loading if this extension method is used
            return query.Include(item => item.PrimaryNode);
        }

        public static IQueryable<Item> IncludeUser(this IQueryable<Item> query)
        {
            // eager loading if this extension method is used
            return query.Include(item => item.User);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the extensions as follows:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var itemQuery = db.Items.IncludeUser();

    itemQuery = itemQuery.IncludePrimaryNode();

    var item = itemQuery.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1);
}
```

It's just another way of doing the same thing, but I like the clarity it adds to the code.